# How to check if a value already exits in a GtkListStore to avoid duplicates?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

How do I check if a value already exists in a `GtkListStore` to avoid duplicates? Dynamically I get values from a database according to a users data input, but if the user types the same or similar word to a previously typed word, it can return the same result, making it so there are not any duplicates values into my `GtkListStore`.

Here's the function that I'm using currently to add the values into `GtkListStore`:

```
static inline void update_c_list(struct al_t *new_list, size_t new_list_size)
{
  struct al_t *l = new_list;
  GtkTreeIter iter;
  size_t i = 0;

  for(; i < new_list_size; i++,l++) {

    if(/* magic to avoid double goes here */) {
    gtk_list_store_append(completionmodel, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(completionmodel, 
               &iter, C_NAME, l->name,
               C_NICK, FOO_STRING(l->foo),
               C_EMAIL, BAA_STRING(l->baa), -1);
    }
  }

  gtk_entry_completion_set_model(completion, GTK_TREE_MODEL(completionmodel));
}
```

Comment: Which data field do you want to compare?

Comment: The value of `C_NAME` that's `l->name`. I'm thinking to use some hash algorithm and do hashing on `l->name` string and store the integer(the hash) into an array of "added already", if not present. So each new string requested to add into GtkListStore, I do hashing on string and look at if such integer is present, if false, add to array of "added already" and my GtkListStore. What do you think? slower?

Comment: Have your array sorted or use a bonary tree, this will gove you O(log n) performance on search and insert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the list and find if same data exists in it.

```
struct CListLooupStruct
{
  gbolean b_found;
  struct al_t *l;
}; 

gbolean search_c_list_func(GtkTreeModel *model, 
                           GtkTreePath *path, 
                           GtkTreeIter *iter, 
                           gpointer data)
{
   gchar name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH];
   CListLooupStruct* lookup = (CListLooupStruct*)data;
   gtk_tree_model_get (model, iter, 0, &name, -1)
   if (/*compare name to lookup->name */)
   { 
       lookup->b_found = TRUE;
       return TRUE;
   }
   return FALSE;
}
```

In your `update_c_list()` function you need to:

```
...
CListLooupStruct c_list_lookup = { FALSE, new_list };    
gtk_tree_model_foreach(completionmodel, search_c_list_func, &c_list_lookup);
if (/* magic to avoid double */ c_list_lookup.b_found == FALSE )
...
```

Comment: I'm afraid this will result in really poor performance at each add, getting worse and worse with the model filled in...

Comment: True. The other option is to use an additional data struct like hash that would keep hashes of already inserted elements.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking about too.